# openCV / unhandled exception or msvcp100d.dll

Tags: exception, opencv, video, visual-studio-2012, unhandled

I do realise that this problem is pretty common, but I have spent around 4 days so far, trying to fix it on my own, using all the smart advice I found on the Internet and - unfortunately - I've failed.

I managed to make openCV2.4.6 work with my VisualStudio 2012, or at least that's what I assumed after I was able to stream a video from my webcam with this example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
CvCapture* capture;
IplImage* newImg;

while (true)
{
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
newImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );

cvNamedWindow("Window1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);    
cvShowImage("Window1", newImg);

int c = cvWaitKey(10);
if( (char)c == 27 ) { exit(0); }   
}

cvReleaseImage(&newImg); 
return 0;

}
```

Everything worked fine, so I decided to play around with it and I made an attempt to use a simple image processing operation such as converting rgb to grayscale. I modified my code to following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"


int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
CvCapture* capture;
IplImage* img1;
IplImage* img2;

while (true)
{
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
img1 = cvQueryFrame( capture );
img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
cvCvtColor(img1,img2,CV_RGB2GRAY);

cvNamedWindow("Window1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvNamedWindow("Window2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

cvShowImage("Window1", img1);
cvNamedWindow("Window2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

int c = cvWaitKey(10);
if( (char)c == 27 ) { exit(0); }

}

cvReleaseImage(&img1);
cvReleaseImage(&img2);


return 0;

}
```

And that's the place where the nightmare started. I keep getting the

> Unhandled exception at at 0x000007FEFD57AA7D in opencvbegginer.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000030F920.

I did some research and tried few solutions, such as exchanging opencv_core246.lib to opencv_core246d.lib, etc. For a second I hoped it might work, but the reality punched me again with msvcp100d.dll missing. I tried to update all redistributable packages, but it didn't change the fact I keep getting this error. I tried to find out how to fix it another way and I found some forum on which they tell to go to C/C++ properties and change the Runtime Library to MTd, so... I tried this as well, but - as you can notice by now - it didn't work.

At this current moment I just ran out of ideas on how to fix this, so I would be really grateful for any help.

Cheers

PS. Important thing to add: when I got the unhandled exception, opencv 'spoke to me', saying

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument  in
>   unknown function, file ......\scr\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp,
>   line 1238

However, I already assumed way back then that I'm just not clever enough with my idiot-resistant code and I tried few other pieces of code that were written by competent people - unfortunately, I keep getting exactly the same error (the rest is the same as well, after I change the things mentioned above).

Comment: Why don't you use the C++ standard? It's easier to begin with. Use `cv::Mat` and `cvtColor`.

Comment: Not going to lie, mostly because I've found much more examples with this one and I'm pretty happy with the fact that I actually can understand some of these. What are the chances THIS is the thing that causes the described issue?

Comment: What line does the assertion get thrown on? Also, @William made an excellent suggestion. The C++ API is much easier to work with, and the C API is deprecated. OpenCV provides some [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html) that can help you get started.

Comment: It's in 

img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);

Comment: Did you check if `img1 = cvQueryFrame( capture );` returns NULL?

Comment: Yes, I did. It returns NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `img1 == NULL`, then it crashes on `cvGetSize(img1)`. Try enclosing the code after `cvQueryFrame` in an `if (img1 != NULL)`.

However, if it returns `NULL` for every frame, it means there is something wrong with your camera/drivers/way you capture the frames.

You should also move the `cvNamedWindow` outside of the loop, since there is no need for it to be recreated for every frame.

Comment: Well, I have done everything you said. It actually helped (!), but a bit only. I don't have any errors now and I have the window with original image from camera working, however the second one, which should show the image in gray, doesn't work as expected. It appears but remains gray and empty.

E: Aight ;) I'm a moron. I did call the window, but haven't stated what I want to show in it. It works fine! You're my hero :)

Comment: @Entalpia In the line after `cvShowImage("Window1", img1);` do you still have a second `cvNamedWindow("Window2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);`. This line should be `cvShowImage("Window2", img2);` to update `img2`.

Comment: Yeah, that was the moron-part I wrote about 10 minutes ago. I changed it to that one right after I noticed it and it started working :)